# Send different items as a string in Python

Tags: python, string, logging, type-conversion

I am trying to make a custom logger for my python application and I am having some issues with parsing the messages. All in a nutshell I want to be able to replace `print(Item[0], "has", numberOfItems, Price[0], Availablity[0])` with my logger: `Logger.Log(Item[0], "has", numberOfItems, Price[0], Availablity[0])`.

On the Logger.py I have:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
dirName = 'Logs'

#def initialiseLogger():
if not os.path.exists(dirName):
    os.mkdir(dirName)

dateTimeObj = datetime.now()
date = dateTimeObj.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
logFileName = dirName + "\\" + "Log." + date + ".log"

LOG_FILE = open(logFileName, "w+")  
LOG_FILE.write("Started log file")

def Log(message):
    dateTimeObj = datetime.now()
    timestampStr = dateTimeObj.strftime("%d:%m:%Y-%H:%M:%S")
    LOG_FILE.write(str(timestampStr) + "::" + message)
```

From the elements that I am trying to print some are not strings, so I get various errors if I try to use `str()`. I tried converting all of the elements into a string and then use `str.join()`, but with no luck.

Is there an easier way to do the conversion or should I think of implementing more logic on the Logger.Log side in order to receive anything I send it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use the builtin `logging` module which has solved most of these problems already?

Comment: What are the 'various' errors that are thrown and where in the code are they thrown from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a perfect case for using `str.format`:

```
Logger.Log("{} has {} {} {}".format(Item[0], numberOfItems, Price[0], Availablity[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks. I’ll give it a try!